# Quotient rings of $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

It seems that $$\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x-a)(x-b) \cong \mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x-a) \times \mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x-b),$$ where $a \neq b$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ ($\mathbb{F}_p = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$). 
How would one prove that. And, apparently, this factorization is not true for $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^2)$.

Comment: Title: Quotients rings of $R=\mathbb{F}_p[x]$.

Comment: More generally, in any principle ideal domain, it is true that $R/\langle mn\rangle \cong R/\langle m\rangle\times R/\langle n\rangle$ if $m,n$ relatively prime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More generally, if $R$ is a commutative ring, and $I,J$ are ideals so that $I+J=R$. Now, there is a natural homomorphism: $R\to R/I\times R/J$. The kernel of this map is $I\cap J$. So this map can be factored:

$$R\to R/(I\cap J)\to R/I\times R/J.$$ with $R/(I\cap J)\to R/I\times R/J$ being one-to-one.

Now we need to prove this is onto.

Write $1=i+j$ with $i\in I,j\in J$.  Given $([r_1],[r_2])\in R/I\times R/J$, we choose $r=r_1j+r_2i$. Then $r-r_1=r_1(1-i)+r_2i-r_1=(r_2-r_1)i\in I$ and similarly $r-r_2\in J$, so $r\to ([r_1],[r_2])$.

So, given that $I+J=R$ we have:

$$R/(I\cap J)\cong R/I\times R/J$$

This is just a generalization of Chinese remainder theorem, with the condition $I+J=R$ replacing the "relatively prime" condition in $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Use the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Generalization_to_arbitrary_rings). $(x - a) - (x - b) = b - a\neq 0$, and $b - a\in\Bbb F_p$, so $(b - a) = (1)$ (as ideals). Then CRT gives you the isomorphism.

CRT does not apply to $(x^2) = (x)(x)$, as $(x) + (x) = (x)\neq \Bbb F_p[x]$. You can also see that it does not hold because $\Bbb F_p[x]/(x - a)\cong\Bbb F_p$ (via $\Bbb F_p[x]/(x - a)\ni p(x) + (x - a)\mapsto p(a)$), and $\Bbb F_p[x]/(x^2)$ has an element $\epsilon$ such that $\epsilon^2 = 0$, but no such element exists in $\Bbb F_p\times\Bbb F_p$.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/713117)

Comment: @amWhy My apologies. I meant the phrase as a joke, and I'm certainly not asking for you to upvote.

Comment: @Stahl, thanks for reply.